# The use of malloc and free: invalid next size error

Tags: c, pointers, multidimensional-array, malloc, free

I'm confused about the usage of malloc and free, here is my example and code:

To be clear, assume we want to read lines from a file and write to a array. The format of the file is:

```
3
abc
def
ghi
jkl
mno
pqr
```

I want to store the first three lines into array1, and put the remaining into array2.

The code:

```
int num;

FILE *fin = fopen("filename", "r");

/*Read the first line of the file*/
fscanf (fin, "%d", &num);

char **array1 = malloc(sizeof(char *) * num);
char **array2 = malloc(sizeof(char *) * num);

/*Apply sizeof(num * num) memory blocks and set the first address to array1[0]*/
array1[0] = malloc(sizeof(char) * num * num);
array2[0] = malloc(sizeof(char) * num * num);

/*Allocate the address of each (char *) array pointer*/
int i;
for (i = 0; i < num-1; i++)
{
    array1[i+1] = array1[i] + num;
}

for (i = 0; i < num; i++)
{
    fscanf(fin, "%s", array1[i]);
}
```

The problem arises when calling the `free` function:

```
/*ERROR: free(): invalid next size (fast): 0x0804b318(gdb)*/
free(array1[0]);
free(array1);
```

Since the address 0x0804b318 is array1[0], I think the memory blocks assigned may not enough. To make it larger:

```
array1[0] = malloc(sizeof(char) * (num+1) * (num+1));
```

And it worked, but I'm confused about this, since the first 3 lines of the file are:

```
abc
def
ghi
```

The `malloc` function returns a pointer to a 3 * 3 char array which is enough to store
the 3 lines, why do we need (3+1) * (3+1)?

Comment: [Please don't cast the return value of `malloc()` in C](http://stackoverflow.com/a/605858/28169).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Strings are stored with a terminating `'\0'`-character, which takes room too. So to store a 3-character string, you need space for 4 characters.